# DrawerLayout over WebView constantly refreshes view

Tags: android, android-webview, drawerlayout, android-espresso

I have a webView that has a DrawerLayout burgernav style that will open over it. The problem is that when the drawer is open, the entire screen constantly refreshes. I can tell from setting the Developer Options setting "Show surface updates". The screen just flashes nonstop. When the drawer closes, the screen stops refreshing. Functionality wise, everything works. The problem is I am using Espresso for Automation testing and this relies on the UI thread. The tests all time out since the constant refreshing blocks the UI thread. Any idea why this might be occurring? Thanks!

One another think I have discovered, it only effects 4.4 (Kitkat) so the old webview is fine.

Comment: Have you found any workarounds for it?